# Consolidate Redundant Condition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, resharper

In a project that I am maintaining, Visual Studio is flagging some code for a high complexity.  The code is creating raw RTF for a print preview, and has numerous lines with the same condition, `If bolprint Then ...`.  Some of the conditionals are one line, others are multi-line.  Not all of the code in this section uses the condition.

I want to cleanly consolidate these conditionals, but I'm not sure how to do so without going one line at a time.  I have ReSharper, but I do not know how to write the SSR for this.

Edit:

The code includes both one-line conditionals and conditional blocks.  Further complicating things, there are also lines that aren't conditional, so I can't just wrap the whole block and do a regex find/replace. Some example lines:

```
If bolPrint Then
    If Me.cbxDeltaBC.Checked AndAlso Me.cbxEqualBC.Checked Then Writer.WriteLine("\pard\b0                    Printed by: \b " & strUserLoggedIn _
       & "                 EQUAL and DELTA             Sort by: \b " & cbbSortBC.Text & "\par")
    If Me.cbxDeltaBC.Checked AndAlso Not Me.cbxEqualBC.Checked Then Writer.WriteLine("\pard\b0                    Printed by: \b " & strUserLoggedIn _
       & "                      DELTA                  Sort by: \b " & cbbSortBC.Text & "\par")
    If Not Me.cbxDeltaBC.Checked AndAlso Me.cbxEqualBC.Checked Then Writer.WriteLine("\pard\b0                    Printed by: \b " & strUserLoggedIn _
       & "                      EQUAL                  Sort by: \b " & cbbSortBC.Text & "\par")
End If

If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("\par\ulnone\fs16 ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("(A)               ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("(A)     ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("(A)   ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("    (A)  ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write(" (A&B)             ")
If bolPrint Then Writer.Write("(A&B)   ")
```

Comment: Without an example, we couldn't even start to answer your question.

Comment: @Styxxy Fair enough.  I was assuming that my question was obvious, ignoring the fact that I had written it.  Example added.

Comment: Sorry that you have to maintain smelly VB.Net code like this (your code snippet is probably one of the 'nicer' bits). Clean little bits as you go and it'll become easier to work with in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly Resharper is not going to be able to help you with this I think. You will probably have to clean it up manually. It shouldn't take too long to group statements inside one condition. If there are unit tests then it may make you feel more confident at refactoring this wonderful code. Just do small bits at a time, like the 'boy scout rule' - leave the place in a better state than you found it.